# How to return in a callback?

Tags: c#, sockets, xna

I'm working with C# Sockets, and I need to return a value in an asynchronous callback, or somehow get my desired value out of the method and return it somehow. Here's what I have:

```
public class UdpState
{
    public UdpClient u;
    public IPEndPoint e;
}

class NetworkListener
{
    private const int port = 1222;

    public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(iar.AsyncState)).u;
        IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(iar.AsyncState)).e;
        // line I need to return (byte[]): u.EndReceive(iar, ref e);
    }


    public static void StartListeningForMessage()
    {
        bool done = false;
        IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(ipEnd);
        UdpState udps = new UdpState();
        udps.e = ipEnd;
        udps.u = listener;

        try
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                listener.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), udps);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

As you can see, on the last line of my ReceiveCallback method, it says what I want to return. I can't make the callback directly return anything though. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I could just make a static byte[]. It didn't work before because you need to intialize it, so I did public static byte[] = new byte[0].